# How libssh2 read and write functions works

Tags: c, ssh, libssh2, libssh

I'm not sure if i'm allowed to ask this type of questions here but i hope i'm not violent any rules.
lately i'm reading about SSH and trying to start some basic programs about sending ssh commends to an SSH remote device (my device i a raspberry pi) and i'm using windows and c and language, the libssh2 is working fine but the lack of documentation and i mean the lack of some details about the function specification. I'm still noob about SSH protocol and i'm getting confusing about the difference between those functions and how they works:

```
libssh2_channel_read()
libssh2_channel_write()
libssh2_channel_exec()
```

i manage to run a commend using the `libssh2_channel_exec()` function which send a commend to the SSH remote to run the commend i'm asking for (for example "uptime") and using the `libssh2_channel_read()` i can read the results. but when it comes to the `libssh2_channel_write()` function i have no clue how to use it or what is the difference between write and exec. what i get it the write function will not block the communication (i'm not sure what does that mean).

so to be clear, y question is, what is the difference between `libssh2_channel_write()` and `libssh2_channel_exec()` and how i can use `libssh2_channel_write()` function and read the result.

i will appreciate any link or documentations or tutorial about libssh2 in c.

thank you.

Comment: `write` probably simulates typing in the command. The uptime command doesn't do anything if you type into it. `cat`, for example, does.

Comment: so you mean, i use write when i execute (use exec) a command that require typing something and to exit that process i finish with eof (function in ssh2 to send end signal)?
and can you explain the "nonBlocking" term they talking about.